# Get Comma Seperated Taxonomy Linked Terms and Last Child Separated By "&" Instead Of Comma

Tags: functions, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

I Want to List Custom Taxonomy Terms with Link and Separate Each with Comma but add "&" before the last term.

Example:

> [Drake](https://#), [Migos](https://#), [Ciara](https://#) & [Nicki](https://#)

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65577605/12134321) that shows how to add '&' before the last term. BUT the terms are not **linked** which is what I am trying to achieve.

MY CURRENT CODE:

```
 $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'artist' );
            foreach($terms as $index => $term) {
                $enIndex = sizeof($terms) - 2;
    $end = (isset($terms[$enIndex]) && $index == $enIndex ? ' & ' : ', ');
    $entry_terms .= $term->name . $end;
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term );               
            }
            $entry_terms = rtrim( $entry_terms, ', ' );
                                       
 echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $entry_terms . '</a>';
```

CURRENT RESULT OF MY CODE:

> [Drake, Migos, Ciara & Nicki](https://#nicki)

My code is not working fine. It links all terms to the last term link only. Please help check my code. I am new WordPress development. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking is a generic PHP/programming question, and this: "*It links all terms to the last term link only*", is because your code clearly is attaching the link (i.e. the last value assigned to `$term_link`) to the entire list (`$entry_terms`), i.e. `echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $entry_terms . '</a>'`.

So what you should have done is, attach the link to the term name on this line: `$entry_terms .= $term->name . $end;`, like so:

1. Replace this part:

   ```php
   $entry_terms .= $term->name . $end;
   $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
   ```

   with this:

   ```php
   $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
   $entry_terms .= '<a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>' . $end;
   ```

And then, after that:

1. Replace the `$entry_terms = rtrim( $entry_terms, ', ' );` with `echo rtrim( $entry_terms, ', ' );`.
2. **Remove** the `echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $entry_terms . '</a>';`.

#### Additional Notes

1. You should define `$entry_terms` before the `foreach` line, i.e. add `$entry_terms = '';`.
2. The ampersand sign is being *displayed* to the user, hence you need to escape the character, i.e. use `' &amp; '` instead on line 4 in your original code.

Comment: I have adjusted my code accordingly and it works flawlessly. thanks pal.